# Given the index value how can I update only those values in a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, update-attributes

I have a nested form as detailed below with a checkbox which I'm hoping to use to note only the records I want to update.  I've checked the html and I'm registering the correct index for each record with it.  The html for both an example attribute and the checkbox are as follows:

```
<input id="game_game_rosters_attributes_0_game_id" name="game[game_rosters_attributes][0][game_id]" type="hidden" value="127">
<input id="add_0" name="add[0]" type="checkbox" value="false">
```

Now, I *think* I'm supposed to figure out which `game_roster_attributes` I want to update by checking to see if the checkbox with the same index has a value of "true".  But I'm unsure how to do this in my games_controller.rb, because it's currently set to mass assignment of my attr_accessible variables with `@game.update_attributes()`...

***games_controller.rb***

```
def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @game.update_attributes(params[:game])
       format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
    else
       format.html { render action: "edit"}
       format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entry }
    end
  end
end
```

***Nested Form***

```
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>

   # @game fields for editing here...

   <% roster_options.each.with_index do |option, index| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :game_rosters, option do |fields| %>
        <%= fields.object.player.full_name %>
        <%= fields.hidden_field :player_id %>
        <%= fields.hidden_field :game_id %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'add[' + index.to_s + ']', false %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**Models**

***game.rb***

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :game_rosters_attributes
  has_many :game_rosters
  has_many :players, :through => :game_rosters
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_rosters, allow_destroy: true
end
```

***game_roster.rb***

```
class GameRoster < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :winner, :player_id, :game_id, :placement
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :player
end
```

***game_controller.rb***

```
def new
  @game = Game.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @game }
  end
end

def edit
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @game_roster = GameRoster.joins(:player).where(game_id: params[:id]).order('winner DESC, placement DESC')
  @options = SeasonRoster.where("season_id = (?) AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM game_rosters INNER JOIN games ON games.id = game_rosters.game_id WHERE game_rosters.player_id = season_rosters.player_id AND games.id = (?))", @game.season_id.to_s, @game.id.to_s)

  @roster_options = Array.new
  @options.each do |o|
    c = GameRoster.new
    c.player_id = o.player_id
    c.challenge_id = params[:id]
    c.winner = false
    @roster_options.push(c)
  end

end
```

Comment: How do your models associations look? How does your controller new/edit look: do you build a set of rosters, which are then rendered, so you "prepare" empty rosters, but you do not want to save all of them? Is that it?

Comment: @nathanvda, The way it's currently working is I already have the games in my database.  Now I'm just in the process of adding players to those games, but only the players that are part of the season are eligible to be added to the game.  Some, but not all of the players are added to games. So I'm just trying to add a checkbox method to specify which ones shown need to be added, since currently I'm creating a new `GameRoster` record for each eligible player. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after taking some time away from the problem and coming back to it I found a simple enough solution.  I ended up just reversing the :_destroy checkbox that I had been using in the mean time.

```
<%= fields.check_box :_destroy, {}, '0', '1' %>
```

Basically, I just reversed the value of what the check box would usually represent.  You can see where I edited the nested form to use this method below.

**Nested Form**

```
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>

   # @game fields for editing here...

   <% roster_options.each.with_index do |option, index| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :game_rosters, option do |fields| %>
        <%= fields.object.player.full_name %>
        <%= fields.hidden_field :player_id %>
        <%= fields.hidden_field :game_id %>
        <%= fields.check_box :_destroy, {}, '0', '1' %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your requirement. I assume that you want to save only those rosters with their 'add' field checked and remove the rest of them.

**roster.rb**

```
class Roster < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :add
end
```

**game.rb**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :mark_rosters_for_removal

  def mark_rosters_for_removal
    rosters.each do |roster|
      unless roster.add
        roster.mark_for_destruction
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Nested Form**

```
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>

   # @game fields for editing here...

   <% roster_options.each.with_index do |option, index| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :game_rosters, option do |fields| %>
       <%= fields.object.player.full_name %>
       <%= fields.hidden_field :player_id %>
       <%= fields.hidden_field :game_id %>
       <%= fields.check_box :add, false %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I didn't think to use another attribute to check for it.  However, it seems a little funny to have an attribute that is used in this way as it holds no value to the model after the saving process is complete.  Would it not be better to have the check boxes just note the records to save without being attached to the model? Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a before_save and use the params hash to check to see if the check-box is checked or not. Then use the .delete method to delete that part of the params hash. Then `@game.update_attributes()` would only update the rosters that are still in the hash (whom's check-boxes are checked).

Nested Form

```
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>

   # @game fields for editing here...

   <% roster_options.each.with_index do |option, index| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :game_rosters, option do |fields| %>
        <%= fields.object.player.full_name %>
        <%= fields.hidden_field :player_id %>
        <%= fields.hidden_field :game_id %>
        <%= check_box_tag :add, false %>  #Notice change!!!!!
     <% end %>
   <% end %>

<% end %>
```

game.rb

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_for_deletion

  ...

  def check_for_deletion
    index = 0
    roster = params[:game][:game_rosters_attributes]
    while !roster["#{index.to_s}"].nil?
      if roster["#{index.to_s}"][:add] == "true"  # Or "checked" or whatever. I forget the actual value
        roster.delete "#{index.to_s}"
      end
      index += 1
    end
  end
end
```

You might have to play around with this a bit depending on how your params hash looks like. I did my best to figure it out. I'm also not 100% that "#{index.to_s}" will work (or it could even be overkill). But this should give you a good head start.

Comment: I'm working on trying to get this answer to work, however you are using params in the model.  I'm currently trying to figure out how to pass it to the model. - Also looks like the hash shows only one ":add" value instead of one for each game_rosters

Comment: @moopasta I didn't think of that. However, if you copy and paste that code into your controller and instead put `before_action :check_for_deletion, only: :update` it should work the same and have access to params. Now, it is interesting that there is only one :add value. It should be nested within each game_roster. Either way, you could go back to your original code: `<%= check_box_tag 'add[' + index.to_s + ']', false %>` and edit the other code accordingly. If you could copy/paste your params output, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are adding all players to a game and then deleting them on update if "add" is not checked.

If this is the case, then you can add a checkbox for _destroy and it will be handled for you, as you have added the "allow_destroy: true" flag on game_rosters in game.rb.

Note that it will now be a "remove" checkbox rather than an "add" checkbox.

Nested Form:

```
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>

  # @game fields for editing here...

   <% roster_options.each.with_index do |option, index| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :game_rosters, option do |fields| %>
     <%= fields.object.player.full_name %>
     <%= fields.hidden_field :player_id %>
     <%= fields.hidden_field :game_id %>
     <%= fields.check_box :_destroy, false %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>

<% end %>
```

From the Rails guide on nested forms:

> "Don't forget to update the whitelisted params in your controller to also include the _destroy field"

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: yes this is how I currently have been setting it up however because Players get eliminated as the games progress - it's less efficient to check off the ones to remove rather than add in this case.

Comment: I see, so you are still looking for the opposite to the _destroy param.

Comment: yes but I found a solution I added as an answer. Basically just reversing the values of the enabled/disabled states. Not sure why I didn't think of it before.